# Get ID from a FASTA file with Biopython

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

I am using Biopython to get some information from FASTA file with nucleotide sequences.
However, I'd like to get only the ID and the sequence from this file.
I have this code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

for seq_nucleotides in SeqIO.parse("CDS_sequence.txt", "fasta"):
   print(seq_nucleotides.description)
   print(seq_nucleotides.seq)
```

And got this:

lcl|NC_000913.3_cds_NP_414584.1_1 [gene=fixB] [locus_tag=b0042] [db_xref=UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot:P31574] [protein=putative electron transfer flavoprotein FixB] [protein_id=NP_414584.1] [location=43188..44129] [gbkey=CDS]

ATGAACACGTTTTCTCAAGTCTGGGTATTCAGCGATACCCCTTCTCGTCTGCCGGAACTGATGAACGGTGCGCAGGCTTTAGCTAATCAAATCAACACCTTTGTCCTCAATGATGCCGACGGCGCACAGGCAATCCAGCTCGGCGCTAATCATGTCTGGAAATTAAACGGCAAACCGGACGATCGGATGATCGAAGATTACGCCG ...

I need to get only the **protein_Id = NP_414584.1** and the sequence. But I don't know how to extract the ID from the string description and get something like this:

NP_414584.1

ATGAACACGTTTTCTCAAGTCTGGGTATTCAGCGAT...

Comment: Please copy the full header and some of the sequence from your FASTA file into the question, using the code formatting button to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from Bio import SeqIO

def sequence_extract_fasta(fasta_files):
    # Defining empty list for the Fasta id and fasta sequence variables
    fasta_id = []
    fasta_seq = []

    # opening given fasta file using the file path
    with open(fasta_files, 'r') as fasta_file:
        # extracting multiple data in single fasta file using biopython
        for record in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, 'fasta'):  # (file handle, file format)
        
            # appending extracted fasta data to empty lists variables
            fasta_seq.append(record.seq)
            fasta_id.append(record.id)
    return fasta_id, fasta_seq
```

Comment: Depending on the task, it could be convenient just to delete description `record.description = ""` & save `SeqRecord` objects to the list for further processing.